# UISliders lose target action when in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uislider

I am trying to create a page of UISliders. The amount of sliders is dynamic.

I have a PageViewController class and when I put the UISliders in a subview of PageViewController the sliders work.

I would like to encapsulate the sliders into a UIView subclass so I can save their state/change coupled labels, etc. However when I do it the sliders stop working. I've tried a few things and am at the point to where I think I may just be missing a fundamental understanding that hopefully someone can point out.

This works (from PageViewController.m):

```
if ([[controlData type] isEqualToString:@"SliderInt"])
{

  NSDictionary *data = controlData.data;
  NSLog(@"build SliderInt %@ %@ %@", [controlData.data objectForKey:@"min"], [controlData.data objectForKey:@"max"], [controlData.data objectForKey:@"value"]);

  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(startX, startY, 200.0, 22.00);
  UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

  [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
  slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
  slider.continuous = YES;
  slider.value = 25.0;

  CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(startX, startY+22.0, 100.0, 30.0);
  UILabel  *minLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
  [minLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
  minLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
  [minLabel setText:@"minLabel:"];


  labelFrame = CGRectMake(startX+200.0, startY+22.0, 100.0, 30.0);
  UILabel  *maxLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
  [maxLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
  maxLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
  [maxLabel setText:@"maxLabel:"];


  labelFrame = CGRectMake(startX+220.0, startY+0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
  UILabel  *valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
  [valueLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
  valueLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
  [valueLabel setText:@"valueLabel:"];


  minLabel.text =      [data objectForKey:@"min"];
  maxLabel.text =      [data objectForKey:@"max"];
  valueLabel.text =    [data objectForKey:@"value"];
  slider.minimumValue =  [[data objectForKey:@"min"]    intValue];
  slider.maximumValue =  [[data objectForKey:@"max"]    intValue];
  slider.value =      [[data objectForKey:@"value"]  intValue];
  //
  [contentView addSubview:slider];
  [contentView addSubview:minLabel];
  [contentView addSubview:maxLabel];
  [contentView addSubview:valueLabel];
  [slider release];
  [minLabel release];
  [maxLabel release];
  [valueLabel release];
  startY+=60;
}
if ([[controlData type] isEqualToString:@"SliderFloat"])
{
  NSLog(@"build SliderFloat");
}
```

However moving it into this class breaks it

```
@interface SliderIntView : UIView {
    UILabel *minLabel;
    UILabel *maxLabel;
    UILabel *valueLabel;
    UISlider *slider;
    NSDictionary *data;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UISlider *slider;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel    *minLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel    *maxLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel    *valueLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary   *data;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withData:(NSDictionary *)controlData;
-(void) sliderAction:(id) sender;
@end
```

The implementation

```
#import "SliderIntView.h"


@implementation SliderIntView

@synthesize slider, minLabel, maxLabel, valueLabel, data;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame  withData:(NSDictionary *) controlData {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.data = controlData;
        float startX = frame.origin.x;
        float startY = frame.origin.y;

        slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [slider  addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(startX, startY+22.0, 100.0, 30.0);
        minLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [minLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        minLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [minLabel setText:@"minLabel:"];


        labelFrame = CGRectMake(startX+200.0, startY+22.0, 100.0, 30.0);
        maxLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [maxLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        maxLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [maxLabel setText:@"maxLabel:"];


        labelFrame = CGRectMake(startX+220.0, startY+0.0, 100.0, 30.0);
        valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        [valueLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
        valueLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [valueLabel setText:@"valueLabel:"];


        minLabel.text =         [data objectForKey:@"min"];
        maxLabel.text =         [data objectForKey:@"max"];
        valueLabel.text =       [data objectForKey:@"value"];
        slider.minimumValue =   [[data objectForKey:@"min"]     intValue];
        slider.maximumValue =   [[data objectForKey:@"max"]     intValue];
        slider.value =          [[data objectForKey:@"value"]   intValue];
        [self addSubview:slider];
        //[self addSubview:maxLabel];
        //[self addSubview:minLabel];
        //[self addSubview:valueLabel];


    }
    return self;
}
-(void) sliderAction:(id) sender
{
    NSLog("@never happens");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` for your new subclass? Is your view sure to cover the whole area your sliders take up?

Comment: I hadn't but it doesn't seem to make a difference. UPDATE: The top one just started working. I believe it is some form of masking blocking user input.

Comment: Ah, just saw your own answer. Good. :)

Answer (score 0):

The frame was the offending code. I just needed to start the slider with it's own frame as opposed to using the one passed in.

```
float startX = frame.origin.x;
float startY = frame.origin.y;

slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

needs to be

```
slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 250, 22.0)];
```